# Angular - Include librairie files in root application

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have a librairie which have a `js` folder, which contains multiples js files.

When I build it, I success to include all files in builded librairie. So, files are on `dist/my-lib/lib/js`.

But, I cannot access to those files from URL via `http://localhost:4200/lib/js` for example. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the needed folder from `dist` to what you want, thanks to assets.

**Angular.json:**

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "assets": [
              "dist/my-lib/lib/js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```